# How to generate a clickable array/list in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, onclick

I'm trying to make a list to render on an HTML page using a JavaScript function. I know that I can use the `DOM.createElement("LI")`, but I want each item of the list to have a different attribute so that, upon clicking that piece of the list, it re-iterates the function anew.

Here's my current HTML (I'm using the argument of `5` as an example, I'd really have a collection of possible numbers):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="count" onclick="makeAList(5)">Click me too!</p>

<script>
function makeAList(num){
    var itemList = [];
    for (i = 0; i < num; i ++){
        itemList.push(i);
        itemList.forEach(document.setAttribute("onclick", makeAList(i)) = i);
    }
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = itemList;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't get anything to generate when I click on the initial page. How should I fix this? I want it so, when I click on `Click me too!` it will generate `0,1,2,3,4` and then if I click on, say `3`, it renders `0,1,2`.

Comment: You have multiple typos and invalid JS. Debug the errors you get and you'll solve this yourself.

Comment: You can set a click listener by specifying the `onclick` property (eg `element.onclick=...` or `addEventListener`: `element.addEventListener('click',...)` a lot cleaner than using setAttribute and it doesn't look like you are setting it to a valid function anyway

Comment: What is the end goal, do you want to start with `Click me too!` -> user clicks -> it shows `0,1,2` -> user clicks `1` (for example) -> you now show `0,1,2,2` -> user clicks `0` -> you now show `0,1,2,1,2,2` and so on?

Comment: I have an answer but I am also confused about the end goal and don't want to post it yet. Depending on what you want to achieve I can tailor the answer accordingly. Also, if the iteration is only 3 times every time you're not really adding anything it might just replace some values. I think you might want `document.getElementById("count").innerHTML += itemList`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm fairly new at this and the editors I'm using aren't pointing out the errors in the JS. For the end product, I want to click ```Click me too!``` --shows ```0,1,2```--click 1--show-- ```0,1```, so each click only returns the results from that click. I'm going to edit the function to try to make it valid, since I see I'm missing an argument to pull in.

Comment: what you have here looks like it might get awfully confused awfully quickly

Comment: RamRaider, is there a different method for this, or something else that might make the process better or more serviceable?

Comment: You need to clearly define what the end goal is! I would say however that the answer to your question is Yes, almost certainly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I've edited the question to include my desired result at the end, but:
I want it so, when I click on ```Click me too!``` it will generate, where ```Click me too! was, ```0,1,2,3,4``` and then if I click on, say, ```3```, it renders ```0,1,2``` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be changed here.

First, in this scenario I would use `addEventListener` instead of `setAttribute`.

Next, this line `document.setAttribute("onclick", makeAList(i))` will give you a `Maximum call stack size exceeded.` error because by writing the function like so `makeAList(i)` will invoke it then and there, thus continually calling the same function. You can just write `document.setAttribute("onclick", makeAList)`. No argument is needed because, in the next part, you will be able to get the argument from the click event itself.

Next, I would create a new element for each of the items in the array, this way you can determine how many iterations to do based on the `innerText` of each item. Without doing this, regardless of whether or not you click 0, 1, or 2, your target's innerText will be `0,1,2` so you won't be able to adequately determine the right amount of iterations to perform. You separate them into different elements, those elements each get an `onclick` event added to them. And now, when you click that element, in `makeAList` you will have access to that element's `event.target.innerText` which, after using `parseInt` will give you an integer you can use as the iteration length.

Finally, once you have an array of generated elements based on the iteration length gathered from the event, you can clear the innerHtml of your target (`document.getElementById("count")`) by setting it equal to `''`. Then you loop through your array of elements and use `append` to append them to your target.

You can also adjust your formatting by setting the CSS of your elements to `display; inline-block;` and using the below conditional determine where to add a comma.

`p.innerHTML = i < ln - 1 ? i + ', ' : i`

```js
function makeAList(){
    var itemList = [];
    var ln = parseInt(event.target.innerText) >=0 ? parseInt(event.target.innerText) + 1 : 3
    for (i = 0; i < ln; i ++){
        var p = document.createElement('P')
        p.innerHTML = i < ln - 1 ? i + ', ' : i
        p.addEventListener("onclick", makeAList)
        itemList.push(p);
    }
    
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = ''
    
    itemList.forEach((x)=>{
      document.getElementById("count").append(x)
    })
}
```

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p id="count" onclick="makeAList()">Click me too!</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works, thanks! 

So I can understand, the ```parseInt(event.target.innerText)``` determines what the text, as an integer, is inside of the ```<p>``` created upon the click. Is there a similar method for text or other data types?

Comment: I just used `parseInt` because the `event.target.innerText` is a string by nature as that is how it stored in the `DOM` and in this scenario we needed a number to determine iteration amount. However, if you wanted a string, you can just do `event.target.innerText` with no `parseInt`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!